# How to change image on hover in one div by hovering image in another div?

Tags: html, css

**HI**

i have 5 divs.
 suppose ( div class="part1" class="part2" class="part3" class="part4" class="part5" all are floated to left with width:20%) so they are aligned in one line.

Each div contain 2 images suppose image1 with id "top" and image2 with id "bottom"(respectively in all divs).

Now what i do is that i put opacity of all images having id "bottom" to 0 and on hovering on image "top" i change "bottom" opacity to 1 and "top" opacity to 0.

Its working fine till now.

**Now what i want is that**
I want 3rd image in part 1 div with id suppose id="yellow" .

Now when the web loads i want to show "top" id image in part 1.

when the user hovers on part 1 id="top" image i want to show id="bottom"  image (till now i am achieving this)

Now if user hovers on part2,part3,part4,part5 i want to show image with id="yellow" in part 1.

I tried using pseudo selectors +, ~ etc but soon i realised that they only work when a div is under the other div or inside a parent div respectively. But in my case PART1 is before part2 so on.. so i cant change order. P.S. i know its possible with JS jquery but i dont want to use them.

some code

```
   < div class="part1">
<img1 id="top"></img>  colored image with happy child
<img2 id="bottom"></img> yellow image with sad child
<img3></img>    plain yellow image
</div> 

  < div class="part2">
<img1 id="top"></img> colored image with happy child
<img2 id="bottom"></img> yellow image with sad child
 </div> 
 <div class="part3">
<img1 id="top"></img> colored image with happy child
<img2 id="bottom"></img> yellow image with sad child
</div> 
 < div class="part4">
<img1 id="top"></img> colored image with happy child
 <img2 id="bottom"></img> yellow image with sad child
 </div>  
  < div class="part5">
 <img1 id="top"></img> colored image with happy child
 <img2 id="bottom"></img> yellow image with sad child
  </div>
```

now i want to show yellow id image in part 1 when i hover on part2- part5
i.E. i dont want to show images with id top and bottom respectively only in part1 just tha image with id yellow

Comment: you need some js code

Comment: @abidibo i know but only pure html  css is it possible?

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: From my understanding of what you're after, js would be the approach to take (even if css was possible, it would be buggy and very unclean code). Stick to what they're made to do. - and js is made for this.

Comment: I imagine that when hovering .part2 you want a yellow image in .part1, .part3 and .part4, so no, I don't think so. You could do something with pseudo elements, positioning them as absolute and covering the other divs, but 1 - you only have 2 pseudo elelements, while you need 3. 2 - you can't calculate coordinates so you need all elements to be absolute positioned and with fixed dimensions. While using js this is a very easy task.

Comment: Actually i know JS will do it but i achieved all this functionality with html css so for this last task in my project i want to stick with html css.@jbutler483.

Comment: @abidibo no not in rest .part2 so on.. I only want #yellow image in part 1 when hovering on part2 so on to part5. part1 - part5 show there respective bottom images on hovering them as i described in my question.

Comment: please review my updates in question @abidibo

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan se my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hacky maybe and might not be suitable for your case, but since you have only one yellow part, you can use the parent's hover to display the yellow and override that when actually hovering part1.

```
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
    display: none;
}
.parts:hover .yellow {
    display: block;
}
.parts .part1:hover .yellow {
    display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/501b7yry/) with half-size boxes.
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/501b7yry/1/) with full-size boxes.

Comment: actually this is some what close to what i need but what i want is complete yellow image on hovering other parts in your case its partially red and partially yellow. and so on in all parts like partially grey and partially red or green.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear from your question if top/bottom refer to the position inside the parts' divs or to layers. See second demo for fully colored boxes.

Comment: Still, my solution applies. Only significant difference is that my parent div has the class "parts" instead of your "container".

Comment: Oh, that was the new answer. Never mind. But you will need a container div to achieve it with CSS.

Comment: iam going to give ur full boxes demo a try now ;)

Comment: Done it was perfect :) demo full size boxes helped me big time. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE!

Now if you move the cursor from part2 directly back to part1, the yellow part disappears. Fixed using a fake transparent element which captures the hover of the yellow pseudo element.

---

You need a container element.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/abidibo/pen/LEMGQY

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="part1">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="fake"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="part2">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="part3">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="part4">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="part5">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.fake {
  z-index: 1001;
  background: transparent;
}
div[class^=part] {
  float: left;
  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
}
div[class^=part] > div, .fake {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
div[class^=part]:hover .top {
  opacity: 0;
}
div[class^=part]:hover .bottom {
  opacity: 1;
}
.top {
  background: blue;
}
.bottom {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
.part2:hover:before, .part3:hover:before, .part4:hover:before, .part5:hover:before {
  content: '';
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.part3:hover:before {
  left: -200%;
}
.part4:hover:before {
  left: -300%;
}
.part5:hover:before {
  left: -400%;
}
```

And finally, just a suggestion. Is not a good practice, actually it is wrong, to use same id attributes inside the same document, use classes instead. IDS should be unique.

Comment: 1) iam using images not the background color. 2) all images in al part classes have absolute position

Comment: That's a valid alternative to my answer. However, it has a minor flaw: if you move the cursor from part2 directly back to part1, the yellow part stays visible.

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: We are using divs with background-colors to ILLUSTRATE how to achieve the desired result. Just replace div with img in your CSS.

Comment: @Paul is right. I don't have time to use images to create a demo, but it is the same thing. And yes, when moving the cursor from part2 directly back to part1, the yellow part stays visible

Comment: @Paul, now the weird "from .part2 to .part1" bahavior is fixed

Comment: Nice solution using that extra fake element. +1